# Issue with groupby() giving different results

Tags: python, python-2.7

I don't understand why I get two different results when I change the order of the two lines within the for loop:

```
def in_degree_distribution(digraph):
    """
    :param digraph: a directed graph, represented as a dictionary
    :return:
    """
    in_degrees = compute_in_degrees(digraph)
    di = sorted(in_degrees.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))
    distribution = {}
    for k, g in groupby(di, key=itemgetter(1)):
        print k, map(itemgetter(0), g)
        distribution[k] = len(map(itemgetter(0), g))

    return distribution
```

I get

```
{0: 0, 1: 0}
```

but when I put the print statement below the assignment, I obtain a different result

```
def in_degree_distribution(digraph):
    """
    :param digraph: a directed graph, represented as a dictionary
    :return:
    """
    in_degrees = compute_in_degrees(digraph)
    di = sorted(in_degrees.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))
    distribution = {}
    for k, g in groupby(di, key=itemgetter(1)):
        distribution[k] = len(map(itemgetter(0), g))
        print k, map(itemgetter(0), g)

    return distribution
```

In this case I get the output that I want , but I don't know why g looks empty when I put first the print statement

```
{0: 1, 1: 2}
```

Comment: Your second code block is incorrectly formatted, you might want to double check it is the exact code you are running, as this wouldn't be executable.

Comment: `groupby` yields an iterator over each group, you can only consume it once and then it's exhausted.